# Maximo Conditional expression manager/Sql Query Builder

Tags: maximo

Can somebody help me in converting below mentioned query in to Maximo's where clause:

select distinct workorder.wonum from workorder inner join [assignment] 
On workorder.wonum=[assignment].wonum
inner join amcrew
On amcrew.amcrew=[assignment].amcrew
inner join amcrewlabor
On amcrewlabor.amcrew=amcrew.amcrew
inner join labor
On amcrewlabor.laborcode=labor.laborcode 
inner join person 
on labor.laborcode=person.personid where amcrewlabor.laborcode='*KELLYB*'

- KELLYB is PERSONID used here for just reference.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a custom search query in Maximo, you can try prepending your with `in (your query)`

For example, if you're in Maximo's work order tracking module, the application uses `select * from workorder` by default. Any time you add a search filter such as work order number (`wonum`), then the query appends to run a query as `select * from workorder where wonum = '123'` if 123 is the work order number you entered.

[image]

Your where clause might look something like this:

```
wonum in (
select distinct workorder.wonum 
from workorder  
join assignment on workorder.wonum=assignment.wonum
join amcrew on amcrew.amcrew=assignment.amcrew 
join amcrewlabor on amcrewlabor.amcrew=amcrew.amcrew
join labor on amcrewlabor.laborcode=labor.laborcode
join person on labor.laborcode=person.personid
where amcrewlabor.laborcode='KELLYB'
)
```

The SQL that is generated in Microsoft Access will not necessarily work in Maximo without some modification.